# SQL query with INNER join takes too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB where I save scraped proxies and then I check them constantly, the problem is that I have a function which counts the total proxies using a specified filter for example: HTTP proxies from USA with at least 70% of uptime and it takes like 4 - 5 seconds, its not a lot of time but the user can't wait this time to get the counter updated.

To filter all the proxies I use 2 tables in this case
table called proxies, here I insert the proxy with general information, ISP, country, protocols etc

```
CREATE TABLE `proxies` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `port` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `ishttp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `ishttps` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `issocks4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `issocks5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `isp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `ismobile` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `isdetected` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `date_added` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `last_checked` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7981 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and the table called http, here I insert ONLY the http proxies and I save the uptime, failed checks, average ping etc (the proxies are duplicated in the both tables, I mean, if a proxy is HTTP goes to proxies and http)

```
CREATE TABLE `http` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `port` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `total` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `successful` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `failed` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `last_successful` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `last_failed` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `uptime` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `last_response` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `response_sum` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `avg_response` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `anonimity` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3776 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Actually, to filter the proxies I user INNER JOIN, 
here an example:

`SELECT * FROM http INNER JOIN proxies ON http.ip=proxies.ip WHERE ishttp='yes' AND country='USA' AND uptime >= '50'`

Thats just an example, the user can filter by anonimity (http.anonimity), country (proxies.country), uptime (http.uptime), ping (http.avg_response), only mobile proxies (proxies.ismobile) and only passed proxies (proxies.isdetected)

I also want to add that the counter gets updated  (means that the system do a query) using JS and each time that the user modify any value from the form

Comment: Posts asking for performance tuning help normally require you to include a query plan output before any useful suggestions can be made

Comment: Always prefix columns with the table alias when your query includes multiple tables. Repeat after me.

Comment: Which others queries are you also using... As it might change index choices and how to define them..

Comment: *"Thats just an example, the user can filter by anonimity (http.anonimity), country (proxies.country), uptime (http.uptime), ping (http.avg_response), only mobile proxies (proxies.ismobile) and only passed proxies (proxies.isdetected)"* Can you add those queries so we have a idea how the queries are ..

Comment: well is just as the example but adding for example AND ismobile='yes'. AND isdetected='no' (ofc, not all the queries use filter by uptime or country, up to the user)

Answer (score 0):

The key aspect of optimization in your query is the filtering criteria. The most selective one seems to be: first `proxies.country`, and second `proxies.ishttp`.

Therefore I would create the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on proxies (country, ishttp);

create index ix2 on http (ip, uptime);
```

Comment: what to do then? I never created an index

Comment: That explains the slow response time. You can run those two SQL statements to create the indexes. Then you can try your query again, and see if there's any diffeence.

Comment: seems to work, so each time that I want to get the amount of proxies with an specific filter, I will have to create 2 indexs and then execute the query??

Comment: No. The indexes need to be created only once. Then, you can run the query many times (with different parameters).

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM http h INNER JOIN
     proxies p
     ON h.ip = p.ip
WHERE p.ishttp = 'yes' AND p.country = 'USA' AND
      h.uptime >= '50';
```

For this query, there are two indexes approaches, depending on how selective the conditions are.  One is:

- `proxies(country, ishttp, ip)`
- `http(ip, uptime)`

The other is:

- `http(uptime, ip)`
- `proxies(ip, country, ishttp)`

Which is better depends on selectivity:  if the condition on `uptime` produces fewer rows than the condition on proxies, then use the second set of indexes.  If the opposite, use the first.

Comment: but I have to create an index for each query?

Comment: @ArceDesigns . . . If you want your queries to be performant, then appropriate indexes would really help.

Comment: but as I said, it does a query each time that the user modifies any value so that's a lot of queries = a lot of indexes